# How to install intermediate version if install cannot be done in one step?

Tags: apt, system-installation, 15.04

There are similar questions and answers, but none quite solves my problem.
I have Ubuntu 15.04 and neglected to update. Now 15.04 is EOL.
I **think** know how to edit etc/apt/sources.list to point at the archived versions but how do I specify that I want to then upgrade, for example, to  15.10 (and eventually to 16.10)? I can't do it in one step.

Regarding sources.list: I assume I change the URL to that of the old archives, but do I leave the code name the same initially (so that I can be sure I have all the 15.04 updates)? And then, do I change the code name to the next highest?

Comment: Indeed you can't do it one step and you probably shouldn't even if it was possible. Backing up and install from scratch a supported release is by far the best (and way faster) option. Otherwise you may have to spend days doing the successive upgrades with a huge potential for errors and data loss.

Comment: Thanks. The back up will be all of my files under "home" (and those of one other user)? Just a straight copy to external media? 
What about all of the tools I have installed? L.A.M.P., Android Studio, minidlna etc? Will I have to re-install and reconfigure?

Comment: Backup everything you need (personal files), install the OS as usual then install all the required software.

Comment: @BryanT you should back up at least /home (under which all users reside) and /etc (where you may have some custom configurations). but it would be ideal to just back up all the partitions in their entirety onto external media (this can be done most easily while booting from a livecd).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was really hoping I could trick the upgrade to say 15.10 (like I could have done a few days ago) and then leapfrog to 16.10.
Looks like I have no choice.

Comment: I have done several times two step upgrades of EOL ubuntus... so it is just more time and nerve consuming and learn you how to play with the package managment... So if you are eager to learn... make a backup and do it :).... it just takes more time to check each time the package being removed and "not upgraded". And to warn you - there will be for sure many leftovers in the filesystem... But if you need it fast - better clean working machine i.e. fresh install.

Comment: @Rotislav Kandilarov - I have 15.04 installed now, but when I try to upgrade it "jumps" to 16.04 and fails with "upgrade tool does not support vivid to xerial." (That's 16.04.) How do I force an upgrade to 15.10? Do I use the -d option on do-release-upgrade?